# Base64 string Invalid in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, base64

I am converting image into `base64` string like this.

```
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[imageAsset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(copyOfOriginalImage, 1.0);
```

Then I convert this `NSData` into base64 string like this.

```
strEncoded=[imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:76];
```

I used this [online base64 convertor](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to test my image(use same image in online tool and within my app)

**FROM THE TOOL**

```
 9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAYAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAMwKADAAQAAAABAAAJkAAAAAD/7QA4
```

**FROM THE APP**

```
\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD\/4QBMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAMwKADAAQAAAABAAAJkAAAAAD\/
```

These starting portions are different. But when I converted using online tool that string accepts by my server.But not when I pass from the app.
What is the reason for this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like it is escaping forward slashes. I do not believe `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` does this, but some other languages do (like JSON).

Comment: yeas thats because of json but you can see,, still some characters are different. do u know any reason?

Comment: They are the same sting up until a point. Maybe the tool the tool is appending extra information to the data?